# How to determine the types of all subexpressions in a Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I am working on a Haskell project that requires me to convert a Haskell program to its GHC Core form and annotate each sub-expression with its type.  For example, given the factorial function:

```
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n - 1)
```

In this example, I would like to get the types  of (n==0), 1, ( n * fac (n-1) ),  n,  fac(n-1)  and (n-1).  i.e types for all subexpressions in the program.  How do I proceed with this?

One possibility is to use exprType from CoreUtils.  But then, I will have to query the types of  ( n * fac (n-1) ),  n and fac (n-1)  separately in 3 calls?  Is there a better way to do this?

I think the number of queries can be reduced for 2 reasons: One: The type checking has already been performed and 'some' parts of the program tree annotated with the types. Two: Since I am looking for all possible subexpressions, there is going to be considerable overlap. For eg., since fac is of type Int -> Int, n is of type Int and fac (n-1) is of type Int etc. I think this overlap can be minimized/eliminated by using some form of Inference?

TLDR:  Is there an efficient way to annotate each subexpression in Haskell Core with the corresponding type?

Comment: What makes you think you can avoid making three type queries?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think it's a reasonable question at least (even though I predict a negative answer), since the compiler already needs to know all these types during typechecking.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch For 2 reasons:  One:  The typechecking has already been performed and 'some' parts of the program tree annotated with the types. 
 Two: Since I am looking for all possible subexpressions,  there is going to be considerable overlap.  For eg.  since fac is of type Int -> Int,  n is of type Int and fac (n-1) is of type Int etc.  I think this overlap can be minimized/eliminated by using some form of Inference?

Comment: Please don't comment your own question, but edit it.